# Any way to convert my JSP project into Spring, though it has so many JSP files?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a project which is coded in JSP. It has about 60 jsp files. Now i want to change the code from jsp to spring. So is there any way to do this.
Should i write each jsp file in spring individually or any short cut for this transformation . 
How to start please give any suggestion. 
**Note: There is DATABASE connectivity also.** 
Thanks

Comment: You can use JSP in Spring. Spring is most likely in the backend and JSP is the frontend.

Comment: *" Now i want to change the code from jsp to spring. .... Should i write each jsp file in spring individually..."*. Looks like you are not completely aware of what is Spring and what all things it is capable of doing. Get yourself well-versed with Spring Framework and hopefully, you  will understand what all changes you need to make.

Comment: You can start with both, and replace the JSPs one by one. If there is a pattern in the code, you might even write a converter, to "edit" the original JSP to spring usage.

Answer (score 0):

you can add spring dependencies in your project and can follow MVC pattern where your  (**business logic**) should move to **Controllers** and database related code (Connection to DB, Query to DB) should move into **Services** and you can use your **JSP** files for views only.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is follow Spring model view controller design pattern. some points

1.Add dispatcher servlet in your web.xml file

2.Create spring mvc controllers for each jsp page request.

3.Create service layer for businness logic and transaction management.

4.Create DAO layer for database operations like save,update,delete,getbyId,getAll entites.

5.Follow spring mvc reference doc for more configuration and application context.

6.Study how MVC works and you can use URLRewrite filter for url's security.

Apart from this for database persistant layer my suggestion is to use Hibernate Framework.